# Want my LMS to be SCORM compatible

Tags: scorm

I have an LMS written in ASP.net (VB)  which is AICC compatible. I would like the system to be compatible with SCORM. I am using Articulate to create the Course contents but struggling to find a way to communicate between the contents and the LMS. I know that imsmanifest.xml holding the course details and the javascript files in lms folder are the communication port. Now if I want to track the user activity in course, what should I do?

Comment: I have a reverse requirement here. I have custom LMS written in ASP.NET C# which is SCORM compatible only at the moment. Can you please guide me how can I make my LMS AICC complaint as well in a quick and cost effective way. This is an urgent requirement for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the SCORM run-time environment to capture user activity. This involves launching the content in a frameset or a new window and then providing a JavaScript API that allows the content to Get and Set elements defined by the SCORM data model. If you are implementing SCORM 2004, you will also need to create a sequencing engine that inputs the data exchanged at run-time into a rules interpretation engine to determine how to navigate the learner through the course. For more detail, check out the [technical part of SCORM Explained](http://www.scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/) and drill down into the various sections.